# Using random on swift

Tags: swift, string, random

I am a beginner on swift and I have tried to use random but I have this error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an argument of type 'UInt32'

I don't understand why. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var Person = ["jean Michel" , "antoine roubet" , "samuel demets" , "zater burkov", "Gochnik samuel"]

    var city = ["De Paris","De Monreal","Du Maroc","De Tunis","De sarcelles","De roubaix"]

    @IBOutlet weak var quoteLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func changeQuote() {

        var randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Person.count))
        var thePerson = Person[randomIndex]
        print(thePerson)

        var randomIndex2 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(city.count))
        var theCity = city[randomIndex2]
        print(theCity)

        quoteLabel.text = "le texte est modifié"

    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but important: 1) values should have `lowerCamelCase` names in Swift. `UpperCamelCase` names are reserved only for types. 2) arrays are expressed more clearly by making their names plural. `people` instead of `Person`, `cities` instead of `city`. Plus, then you don't have to add arbitrary words like `the` to distinguish. `let city = cities.randomElement()`. Simple!

Answer (score 1):

In the current context, you can use a range to produce a random index.

```
var randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0...Person.count-1)
var randomIndexTwo = Int.random(in: 0...city.count-1)

var thePerson = Person[randomIndex]
var theCity = city.count[randomIndexTwo]
```

But it may be easier to use the method on array for retrieving a random element because it will be type-safe if your array is empty. And it's one line.

```
var thePerson = Person.randomElement()
var theCity = city.randomElement()
```

Comment: Never right code like ` 0 ..< Person.count`, let alone `0...Person.count-1` It crashes when the `Person` array is empty, and is generally error prone. Use `Array.indices` to get the range of indices in an error-less way. Better yet, just call `.randomIndex()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want your code to compile, simply change

```
var Person = ["jean Michel" , "antoine roubet" , "samuel demets" , "zater burkov", "Gochnik samuel"]
var randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Person.count))
var thePerson = Person[randomIndex]
```

to

```
var Person = ["jean Michel" , "antoine roubet" , "samuel demets" , "zater burkov", "Gochnik samuel"]
var randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Person.count)))
//                ^^^
var thePerson = Person[randomIndex]
```

But even better use `Int.random` as other answers have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the imported C function arc4random().
You can now use Swift’s own native random API.
By calling the `random()` method on any numeric type with the range needed

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var Person = ["jean Michel" , "antoine roubet" , "samuel demets" , "zater burkov", "Gochnik samuel"]

    var city = ["De Paris","De Monreal","Du Maroc","De Tunis","De sarcelles","De roubaix"]

    @IBOutlet weak var quoteLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func changeQuote() {

        let randomIndex = Int.random(in: Person.indices)
        let thePerson = Person[randomIndex]
        print(thePerson)

        let randomIndex2 = Int.random(in: city.indices)
        let theCity = city[randomIndex2]
        print(theCity)

        quoteLabel.text = "le texte est modifié"

    }
}
```

NB: Variable's `randomIndex, thePerson, randomIndex2, theCity` that are never mutated, should be changed constant's

Even better as suggested in the comment below just use the arrays .randomElement()

thus your changeQuote() will be

```
@IBAction func changeQuote() {

    guard let thePerson = Person.randomElement() else { return }
    print(thePerson)

    guard let theCity = city.randomElement() else { return }
    print(theCity)

    quoteLabel.text = "le texte est modifié"
}
```

Comment: You're headed in the right direction, but there's a lot of issues here. 1) unnessary mutablility of `randomIndex`, `thePerson`, `randomIndex2` and `theCity` 2) never write code like `0 ..< Person.count`. It's error prones. Use `array.indices`. 3) You can just use `.randomElement()` on an array, and it does the fiddling with arrays and bounds checking for you

Comment: Thank's @Alexander-ReinstateMonica updated the answer.